# Unbound DNS: How to get source IP address from python mod

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, python

I use Unbound DNS with a custom python module. Based on who sends a query, I want to return different results. How do I get the Source IP from the Python module?

Answer (score 1):

I had this question and though the answer is documented, I found it incredibly hard to find.

https://github.com/jedisct1/unbound/blob/master/pythonmod/examples/resip.py